# c# - Image disappears when rotating

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to rotate the image, but after each turn the image quality deteriorates and eventually the image disappears. How to fix this? Thanks for answer.

Code:

```
public static Bitmap RotateImageByAngle( Image oldBitmap, float angle )
{
    const PixelFormat pf = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
    var newBitmap = new Bitmap( oldBitmap.Width, oldBitmap.Height, pf );
    newBitmap.SetResolution( oldBitmap.HorizontalResolution, oldBitmap.VerticalResolution );
    var gfx = Graphics.FromImage( newBitmap );
    gfx.TranslateTransform( (float)oldBitmap.Width / 2, (float)oldBitmap.Height / 2 );
    gfx.RotateTransform( angle );
    gfx.TranslateTransform( -(float)oldBitmap.Width / 2, -(float)oldBitmap.Height / 2 );
    gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gfx.DrawImage( oldBitmap, new Rectangle( new Point( 0, 0 ), new Size( oldBitmap.Width, oldBitmap.Height ) ) );
    gfx.Dispose();
    return newBitmap;
}
...

private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = RotateImageByAngle( this.pictureBox1.Image, 10 );
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: How do you call `RotateImageByAngle`? do you pass the original image or newly created one?

Comment: This code looks fine but you have to throw away the rotated image and always pass the original one

Comment: You need to keep the original image and not rotate each rotated image.  Every rotation has some quality loss because of the size of pixels

Comment: Neat effect! LB, BlackBear, and Hogan are correct. Your seeing the result of accumulated round off error in the float math.

Comment: I call this method in a timer and do not save the original image. Thanks for help!

Comment: Remove the smoothing mode.

Comment: `this.pictureBox1.Image = RotateImageByAngle( this.pictureBox1.Image, 10 );` Yep, there's the problem. Use a local to store the original image and the current rotation value and pass those instead.

Comment: @BlackBear: you should make your comment an answer.